# How to set Tab Order with RadBuilder

Tags: testing, radbuilder

I am using [RadBuilder](http://www.radbuilder.com/)

I was wondering where in the menu I can adjust the tab orders.

Meaning when I am "edit 1" and click tab what controls if I go to "Edit2"

Answer (score 0):

The tab order is the order in the TreeView list on the left-top corner of the main interface and it is the same of Z-Order. You can press the main menu ->Edit -> Bring to Front and Send to Back menu item to change the Z-Order.